# Issue setting up Swagger.io with JAX-RS project on JBoss / Wildfly 9

Tags: rest, jboss, jax-rs, wildfly, swagger

I implement a project that uses a quite simple JAX-RS backend for providing data to an AngularJS based UI. These are separated modules and deployed on a Wildfly 9. In order to have a nice documentation for the REST endpoints I came across swagger.io that seems a good fit. However, I have trouble setting up swagger following the documentation and examples since my project has a slightly different structure.

**Current status**

I can access http://localhost:8080/service/swagger.json that returns

```json
{
    "swagger": "2.0",
    "info": {
        "version": "1.0.0",
        "title": ""
    },
    "host": "localhost:8080",
    "basePath": "/service",
    "schemes": ["http"]
}
```

However the swagger-ui (swagger.json is correctly linked) does not show any of my REST endpoints.

I think the issue might be related to the basePath or the contextRoot that is set for the Wildfly but that's just a vague guess. Besides that I'm not even sure what swagger JAX-RS implementation to use. I thought since I use Wildfly (JBoss) it should be Resteasy but the swagger Jersey setup docs seem better fitting.

My REST endpoints look e.g. like that http://localhost:8080/service/users/register

**Related resources**

pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
    <artifactId>swagger-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.4</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
    <artifactId>swagger-jaxrs</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.4</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
    <artifactId>swagger-annotations</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.4</version>
</dependency>
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">
    <display-name>service</display-name>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>javax.ws.rs.core.Application</servlet-name>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>
                io.swagger.jaxrs.listing,
                jfs.service.services
            </param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>javax.ws.rs.core.Application</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Jersey2Config</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>io.swagger.jaxrs.config.DefaultJaxrsConfig</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>api.version</param-name>
            <param-value>1.0.0</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>swagger.api.basepath</param-name>
            <param-value>http://localhost:8080/service</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
</web-app>
```

jboss-web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-web>
    <context-root>/service/</context-root>
</jboss-web>
```

UserWebService as example

```
package jfs.service.services;

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import io.swagger.annotations.*;
import jfs.data.dataobjects.UserDO;
import jfs.data.dataobjects.enums.UserType;
import jfs.service.sessions.Session;
import jfs.transferdata.transferobjects.*;

import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import java.util.List;

@Path("/users")
@Api(tags = {"users"}, value = "/users", description = "Operations about user")
public class UserWebService {
    @Inject
    UserService service;

    @POST
    @ApiOperation(value = "Register company",
        notes = "A user account for company will be created.",
        position = 1)
    @Path("/register")
    @Consumes("application/json")
    @Produces("application/json")
    public Boolean registerCompany(RegisterDTO register){
        Boolean result = false;
        result = this.service.registerUser(register.email, register.password, UserType.COMPANY);
        return result;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some try & error I figured a way out to make it working. For the hooking up the swagger-core I switched from manual registration of the resource classes to the automatic scanning and registration. That required to change the configuration and initialization from the web.xml to the BeanConfig with e.g. a servlet.

I don't know about the (dis)advantages of the different approaches if there are any - maybe someone can share some insights.

Other than that, this is a working solution for me now:

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">
    <display-name>service</display-name>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>javax.ws.rs.core.Application</servlet-name>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>javax.ws.rs.core.Application</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>resteasy.scan</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>SwaggerServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>jfs.service.services.SwaggerServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
</web-app>
```

SwaggerServlet.java

```
package jfs.service.services;

import io.swagger.jaxrs.config.BeanConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;

public class SwaggerServlet extends HttpServlet {
    @Override
    public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException {
        super.init(config);

        BeanConfig beanConfig = new BeanConfig();
        beanConfig.setVersion("1.0.0");
        beanConfig.setSchemes(new String[]{"http"});
        beanConfig.setHost("localhost:8080");
        beanConfig.setBasePath("/service");
        beanConfig.setResourcePackage("jfs.service.services");
        beanConfig.setScan(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you. your article has helped me a lot. i was facing the same issue.

Comment: Can you please Help me with swagger documentation of restapi? how you have generation the UI? and I am still not able to see swagger.json.

Comment: Dont you have any class that extends Application of restaEasy?.